# Angular 4 production build throwing errors for HTTP do() and map() functions

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm attempting to deploy a production build of my app onto an Apache server.

I can do this fine using the development build (`ng build`) but when I try to do `ng build --prod` I get syntax errors.

I've tested the app with the `ng serve --prod --sm=true` command and found that the problem is every call to the HTTP service on all my Services.

For live examples visit www.gamerfinder.net/dev

In the console I get errors like

```
ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'do'
vendor.37ef2a1036483bd42043.bundle.js (1,4605)
```

This happens on any page that makes an HTTP call (which is every page except 2 of them).

Unfortunately I can't get the same error to show after using `ng build --prod --sm` (I just get syntax errors this way).

(As a side note, how I can get the same errors from `ng serve` to show up on `ng build`? That would make it easier to show on gamerfinder.net/dev).

### Edit

I've uploaded the source code for the app at: https://github.com/jamiemac262/gamerFinder.

Comment: There's not enough data. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is needed. You can show where you import `do` and `map` operators, for starters.

Comment: My bad, I copied the link to GitHub and forgot to paste it, I'll do that now

Comment: @estus The source code is linked at the bottom of the question, All my HTTP calls are in services in the `user` and `game` directories (`src/app/game` and `src/app/user`)

Comment: it looks like you need to import the rxjs methods. import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'; import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; https://github.com/jamiemac262/gamerFinder/blob/master/src/app/user/user.service.ts

Comment: Check the ways to import RxJS: https://gist.github.com/MichalZalecki/d78c52ec55d7ec7b53f7

Comment: @SrAxi This will significantly increase a bundle. That's why it's a common practice to not do that and import RxJS items one by one.

Comment: @estus Did you read past the 10th line?

Comment: @SrAxi, I've answered your previous comment regarding `import Rx from "rxjs/Rx"`. But no, didn't see that there's a complete summary, white space is too large and the rest were off the screen.

Comment: @estus All good mate, there are several ways to import it. I preffer to import the methods I'll use, but if someone is looking for a quick solution... That could be a way to get tests running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use RxJS operators, they should be imported - unless you're importing entire `rxjs` package, which is usually avoided.

There should be

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

and/or

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
```

in files that use these operators. Alternatively, they can be considered 'core' operators and imported in common place, like `polyfills.ts`.

Comment: well this kinda worked, it got rid of the original errors but now displays a similar error for `catch`. Is that another rxjs?

Comment: Yes. You have to do this for all operators. I personally keep the ones I need in every project (do, map, mergeMap, catch and several others) in polyfills, and the rest are imported in-place.

Comment: thanks @estus I'd have never thought to do this haha

Comment: @JamieMcAllister You're welcome. Several core operators (map, catch) were naturally imported by Http package once and worked out of the box. This was a subject to change, and now all of them should be imported manually.